# Using an ActionListener to output results of calculations with Geometric Calculator

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am in the process of building a Geometric Calculator, but am having difficult implementing the ActionListener. I found some sample code on the Oracle site and modified to fit the visual concept I am trying to do.

I combed through my code looking for typos and incorrect punctuation and either corrected it or did not find anything that stuck out to me. I looked at similar questions on Stack Overflow and in text books, and my code looks similar in structure to what is being done in the examples. I have pasted the relevant section of the code below.

Eclipse gives me this error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    CalcButtonListenerA cannot be resolved to a type   I don't understand why this is happening. I thought these lines would take care of resolving the type:

```
            `calcButton1 = new JButton("Calculate");
    calcButton1.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListenerA());`
```

The other relevant code is below...

```
package layout;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GeometryCalculator implements ItemListener {
    JPanel calcTools; 
    final static String CIRCLEPANEL = "Circle Calculator";
    final static String RECTANGLEPANEL = "Rectangle Calculator";
    final static String TRIANGLEPANEL = "Triangle Calculator";


    private JLabel messageLabel1;
    private JLabel messageLabel2;
    private JLabel messageLabel3;
    private JLabel radiusLabel;
    private JLabel baseLabel;
    private JLabel heightLabel;
    private JLabel lengthLabel;
    private JLabel widthLabel;
    private JLabel circleAreaLabel;
    private JLabel circumferenceLabel;
    private JLabel rectanglePerimeterLabel;
    private JLabel rectangleAreaLabel;
    private JLabel triangleAreaLabel;
    private JTextField choiceTextField;
    private JTextField radiusTextField;
    private JTextField baseTextField;
    private JTextField heightTextField;
    private JTextField lengthTextField;
    private JTextField widthTextField;
    private JButton calcButton1;
    private JButton calcButton2;
    private JButton calcButton3;

    JTextField rectanglePerimeterField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField rectangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField triangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);



    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); 
        String comboBoxItems[] = { CIRCLEPANEL, RECTANGLEPANEL, TRIANGLEPANEL };
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);

        //Create the "calcTools".
        JPanel calcTool1 = new JPanel();
        radiusLabel = new JLabel("Radius");
        circumferenceLabel = new JLabel("Circumference");
        circleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        radiusTextField= new JTextField(10);
        messageLabel1 = new JLabel("Let's make some circle calculations.");
        final JTextField circumferenceField = new JTextField(15);
        circumferenceField.setEditable(false);
        final JTextField circleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        circleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        calcButton1 = new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton1.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListenerA());

        calcTool1.add(messageLabel1);
        calcTool1.add(radiusLabel);
        calcTool1.add(radiusTextField);
        calcTool1.add(circumferenceLabel);
        calcTool1.add(circumferenceField);
        calcTool1.add(circleAreaLabel);
        calcTool1.add(circleAreaField);
        calcTool1.add(calcButton1);

        class CalcButtonListenerA implements ActionListener
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String radius;
                double circumference;
                double circleArea;

                radius = radiusTextField.getText();
                circumference = 2*Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
                String circ = String.valueOf(circumference);
                circleArea = Double.parseDouble(radius)* Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI; 
                String area = String.valueOf(circleArea);

                circumferenceField.setText(circ);
                circleAreaField.setText(area);          

            }
        }

        JPanel calcTool2 = new JPanel();
        messageLabel2 = new JLabel("Let's make some rectangle calculations.");
        lengthLabel = new JLabel("Length");
        widthLabel = new JLabel("Width");
        lengthTextField = new JTextField(10);
        widthTextField = new JTextField(10);
        rectanglePerimeterLabel = new JLabel("Perimeter");
        rectangleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        JTextField rectanglePerimeterField = new JTextField(15);
        rectanglePerimeterField.setEditable(false);
        JTextField rectangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        rectangleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        JButton calcButton2 = new JButton("Calculate");

        calcTool2.add(messageLabel2);
        calcTool2.add(lengthLabel);
        calcTool2.add(lengthTextField);
        calcTool2.add(widthLabel);
        calcTool2.add(widthTextField);
        calcTool2.add(rectanglePerimeterLabel);
        calcTool2.add(rectanglePerimeterField);
        calcTool2.add(rectangleAreaLabel);
        calcTool2.add(rectangleAreaField);
        calcTool2.add(calcButton2);


        JPanel calcTool3 = new JPanel();
        messageLabel3 = new JLabel("Let's make some triangle calculations");
        baseLabel = new JLabel("Base");
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height");
        baseTextField = new JTextField(10);
        heightTextField = new JTextField(10);
        triangleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        triangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        triangleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        JButton calcButton3 = new JButton("calculate");

        calcTool3.add(messageLabel3);
        calcTool3.add(baseLabel);
        calcTool3.add(baseTextField);
        calcTool3.add(heightLabel);
        calcTool3.add(heightTextField);
        calcTool3.add(triangleAreaLabel);
        calcTool3.add(triangleAreaField);
        calcTool3.add(calcButton3);



        calcTools = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        calcTools.add(calcTool1, CIRCLEPANEL);
        calcTools.add(calcTool2, RECTANGLEPANEL);
        calcTools.add(calcTool3, TRIANGLEPANEL);

        pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pane.add(calcTools, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(calcTools.getLayout());
        cl.show(calcTools, (String)evt.getItem());
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Geometry Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        GeometryCalculator demo = new GeometryCalculator();
        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);


        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: @Sergiy My apologies for being unclear. Eclipse gives me this error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 CalcButtonListenerA cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error simply says that at that point the compiler does not know what `CalcButtonListenerA` means. You define the class `CalcButtonListenerA` inside the method `addComponentToPane` however the definition is placed *after* the usage so at that moment the class is not yet defined, this is somewhat equivalent to what would happen with a variable, you can't do the following:

```
int y = x + 5; //what is x?
int x = 10; //even if it's defined below, compiler error
```

You can do this properly in a few ways:

- Define it in the method, as a "local class" but *before* the usage:

  ```
  public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
      class CalcButtonListenerA implements ActionListener
      {
          //...
      }
      //...
      calcButton1.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListenerA());
  }
  ```
- Define it in the class GeometryCalculator not in the method:

  ```
  public class GeometryCalculator implements ItemListener {

      public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

          //...
          calcButton1.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListenerA());
      }

      private class CalcButtonListenerA implements ActionListener
      {
          //...
      }
  }
  ```
- Define it as an anonymous class, this is a compact way to do it if you don't want to use that code in any other actionListener.

  ```
  public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
      //...
      calcButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              //the actionPerformed code of CalcButtonListenerA
          }
      });
  }
  ```

If it was a very important class you could also place it in its own file and import it here.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down my options thoroughly. Problem is solved, but this is excellent for me to think about in future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define a method inside a method.

Use an anonymous class like this (much cleaner) :

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GeometryCalculator implements ItemListener {

    JPanel calcTools;
    final static String CIRCLEPANEL = "Circle Calculator";
    final static String RECTANGLEPANEL = "Rectangle Calculator";
    final static String TRIANGLEPANEL = "Triangle Calculator";


    private JLabel messageLabel1;
    private JLabel messageLabel2;
    private JLabel messageLabel3;
    private JLabel radiusLabel;
    private JLabel baseLabel;
    private JLabel heightLabel;
    private JLabel lengthLabel;
    private JLabel widthLabel;
    private JLabel circleAreaLabel;
    private JLabel circumferenceLabel;
    private JLabel rectanglePerimeterLabel;
    private JLabel rectangleAreaLabel;
    private JLabel triangleAreaLabel;
    private JTextField choiceTextField;
    private JTextField radiusTextField;
    private JTextField baseTextField;
    private JTextField heightTextField;
    private JTextField lengthTextField;
    private JTextField widthTextField;
    private JButton calcButton1;
    private JButton calcButton2;
    private JButton calcButton3;

    JTextField rectanglePerimeterField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField rectangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField triangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);



    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel();
        String comboBoxItems[] = { CIRCLEPANEL, RECTANGLEPANEL, TRIANGLEPANEL };
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);

        //Create the "calcTools".
        JPanel calcTool1 = new JPanel();
        radiusLabel = new JLabel("Radius");
        circumferenceLabel = new JLabel("Circumference");
        circleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        radiusTextField= new JTextField(10);
        messageLabel1 = new JLabel("Let's make some circle calculations.");
        final JTextField circumferenceField = new JTextField(15);
        circumferenceField.setEditable(false);
        final JTextField circleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        circleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        calcButton1 = new JButton("Calculate");

        calcButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String radius;
              double circumference;
              double circleArea;

              radius = radiusTextField.getText();
              circumference = 2*Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
              String circ = String.valueOf(circumference);
              circleArea = Double.parseDouble(radius)* Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
              String area = String.valueOf(circleArea);

              circumferenceField.setText(circ);
              circleAreaField.setText(area);

            }
        });

//        class CalcButtonListenerA implements ActionListener
//        {
//
//            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
//            {
//                String radius;
//                double circumference;
//                double circleArea;
//
//                radius = radiusTextField.getText();
//                circumference = 2*Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
//                String circ = String.valueOf(circumference);
//                circleArea = Double.parseDouble(radius)* Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
//                String area = String.valueOf(circleArea);
//
//                circumferenceField.setText(circ);
//                circleAreaField.setText(area);
//
//            }
//        }



        calcTool1.add(messageLabel1);
        calcTool1.add(radiusLabel);
        calcTool1.add(radiusTextField);
        calcTool1.add(circumferenceLabel);
        calcTool1.add(circumferenceField);
        calcTool1.add(circleAreaLabel);
        calcTool1.add(circleAreaField);
        calcTool1.add(calcButton1);



        JPanel calcTool2 = new JPanel();
        messageLabel2 = new JLabel("Let's make some rectangle calculations.");
        lengthLabel = new JLabel("Length");
        widthLabel = new JLabel("Width");
        lengthTextField = new JTextField(10);
        widthTextField = new JTextField(10);
        rectanglePerimeterLabel = new JLabel("Perimeter");
        rectangleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        JTextField rectanglePerimeterField = new JTextField(15);
        rectanglePerimeterField.setEditable(false);
        JTextField rectangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        rectangleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        JButton calcButton2 = new JButton("Calculate");

        calcTool2.add(messageLabel2);
        calcTool2.add(lengthLabel);
        calcTool2.add(lengthTextField);
        calcTool2.add(widthLabel);
        calcTool2.add(widthTextField);
        calcTool2.add(rectanglePerimeterLabel);
        calcTool2.add(rectanglePerimeterField);
        calcTool2.add(rectangleAreaLabel);
        calcTool2.add(rectangleAreaField);
        calcTool2.add(calcButton2);


        JPanel calcTool3 = new JPanel();
        messageLabel3 = new JLabel("Let's make some triangle calculations");
        baseLabel = new JLabel("Base");
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height");
        baseTextField = new JTextField(10);
        heightTextField = new JTextField(10);
        triangleAreaLabel = new JLabel("Area");
        triangleAreaField = new JTextField(15);
        triangleAreaField.setEditable(false);
        JButton calcButton3 = new JButton("calculate");

        calcTool3.add(messageLabel3);
        calcTool3.add(baseLabel);
        calcTool3.add(baseTextField);
        calcTool3.add(heightLabel);
        calcTool3.add(heightTextField);
        calcTool3.add(triangleAreaLabel);
        calcTool3.add(triangleAreaField);
        calcTool3.add(calcButton3);



        calcTools = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        calcTools.add(calcTool1, CIRCLEPANEL);
        calcTools.add(calcTool2, RECTANGLEPANEL);
        calcTools.add(calcTool3, TRIANGLEPANEL);

        pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pane.add(calcTools, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

//    class CalcButtonListenerA implements ActionListener
//    {
//
//        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
//        {
//            String radius;
//            double circumference;
//            double circleArea;
//
//            radius = radiusTextField.getText();
//            circumference = 2*Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
//            String circ = String.valueOf(circumference);
//            circleArea = Double.parseDouble(radius)* Double.parseDouble(radius)*Math.PI;
//            String area = String.valueOf(circleArea);
//
//            circumferenceField.setText(circ);
//            circleAreaField.setText(area);
//
//        }
//    }



    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(calcTools.getLayout());
        cl.show(calcTools, (String)evt.getItem());
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Geometry Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        GeometryCalculator demo = new GeometryCalculator();
        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);


        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```